# Optimization of padding sub-parts of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing information frame-by-frame of a video-game. The DataFrame contains the data of several games, and the game id is part of the data, as is the frame sequential number.

The problem is that not all games have the same duration so my plots make sense. I want to pad the data on a game-by-game basis so that they are all equally long. In particular, I would like to propagate the values at the last frame.

The code I came up with is quite slow. Since I need to run it every time I perform my analysis, I am wondering if there is a better way (vectorization?) to deal with the process.

Here is my current code (it's a fighting game, hence "rounds" and "hp"):

import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import time

```
def sol1(df):
    rounds = df['i_round'].drop_duplicates().as_matrix()
    df = df.set_index('i_round', drop=False)
    max_n_frames = df['i_frame'].max() + 1
    hp_p1 = np.zeros([rounds.shape[0], max_n_frames], dtype=np.int16)
    hp_p2 = np.zeros([rounds.shape[0], max_n_frames], dtype=np.int16)
    df.sort_values(['i_round', 'i_frame'], inplace=True)

    for i, i_round in enumerate(rounds):
        df_ = df.loc[i_round]
        n_frames = len(df_.index)
        hp_p1[i, :n_frames] = df_['hp_p1']
        hp_p1[i, n_frames:] = hp_p1[i, n_frames-1]
        hp_p2[i, :n_frames] = df_['hp_p2']
        hp_p2[i, n_frames:] = hp_p2[i, n_frames-1]

    return hp_p1, hp_p2

def build_example(size, max_hp, avg_hp_loss_per_frame):
    i_round = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
    i_frame = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
    hp_p1 = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
    hp_p2 = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32)
    round_id = 0
    i = 0
    while i < size:
        hp_loss_p1 = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 2 * avg_hp_loss_per_frame, max_hp, dtype=np.int16))
        hp_loss_p1[0] = 0
        hp_loss_p2 = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 2 * avg_hp_loss_per_frame, max_hp, dtype=np.int16))
        hp_loss_p2[0] = 0
        frames = min(np.where(hp_loss_p1 > max_hp)[0][0], np.where(hp_loss_p1 > max_hp)[0][0], size - i)
        if frames == 0:
            break
        hp_loss_p1 = hp_loss_p1[:frames]
        hp_loss_p2 = hp_loss_p2[:frames]
        if hp_loss_p1[-1] > max_hp:
            hp_loss_p1[-1] = max_hp
        if hp_loss_p2[-1] > max_hp:
            hp_loss_p2[-1] = max_hp
        hp_p1[i:i+frames] = max_hp - hp_loss_p1
        hp_p2[i:i+frames] = max_hp - hp_loss_p2
        i_frame[i:i+frames] = np.arange(0, frames)
        i_round[i:i+frames] = round_id
        i += frames
        round_id += 1

    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'i_round': i_round,
            'i_frame': i_frame,
            'hp_p1': hp_p1,
            'hp_p2': hp_p2,
         }
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test for correctness
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'i_round': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
            'i_frame': [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            'hp_p1':   [9,9,7,2,1,0,
                        9,7,7,7,6,
                        9,9,9,9,9,9,6,6,5,4],
            'hp_p2':   [9,7,7,7,7,3,
                        9,2,2,2,0,
                        9,9,9,9,9,9,3,2,1,0],
         }
    )
    hp_p1, hp_p2 = sol1(df)
    print(hp_p1)
    print(hp_p2)

    # Test for speed
    for size in [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000]:
        df = build_example(size, 500, 10)
        # print(df)
        t0 = time.time()
        sol1(df)
        t1 = time.time()
        print("V1: Time with %d rounds:" % size, t1 - t0)
```

which outputs

```
[[9 9 7 2 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [9 7 7 7 6 6 6 6 6 6]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 6 6 5 4]]
[[9 7 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 3]
 [9 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [9 9 9 9 9 9 3 2 1 0]]
V1: Time with 1000 rounds: 0.010406017303466797
V1: Time with 10000 rounds: 0.06633138656616211
V1: Time with 100000 rounds: 0.6354598999023438
V1: Time with 1000000 rounds: 5.672064304351807
V1: Time with 10000000 rounds: 57.4943950176239
...
```

Comment: Add sample case?

Comment: Took me a while, ready now.

Comment: HI, so you want each game to have the same number of rounds?  rows?   Shouldn't your sample data contain a game id that you mentioned?

Comment: I left out the games identifier and just treated every round as a separate game in order to simplify things. I want every round to have the number of rows (frames). Btw it seems from my build function that the hp is guaranteed to finish with a 0, but that is wrong: again, I removed the opponent HP to simplify, but that means that one of the two hp columns can finish with something other than 0. I will fix the code once I get to my office (it works now as well, but it could be misleading so just consider this)

Comment: @BobHaffner I made the code and the example clearer (I hope)